# MySQL is missing in QGIS 3.30 for MacOS

Tags: qgis, mysql

MySQL is missing in Add Vector layer database option.
Instead, MySQL option is visible with eVis plugin.
On my Mac (intel) MySQL woks fine with other clients outside of QGIS (eg workbench).

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: QGIIS 3.10 and 3.30